# Function/algorithm for determining image (in)homogenity

Tags: image-processing, opencv

SHORT: is there a function in OpenCV or a general algorithm which could return an index for image homogenity?

LONG VERSION :-) I am implementing auto-focus based on image-data evaluation. My images are biological cells, which are spread fairly in similar density across the image area. Unfortunatelly, sometimes my algorithm is disturbed by dirt on the cover glass, which are mostly a few bright spots. So my idea is, to discard focus-function peaks caused by inhomogenious images.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Example images as requested: (not the best ones, but should fairly show the problem)
[image: auto-focused on dirt-ERROR]
[image: auto-focused on cells-OK]

The left image captured at wrong Z-position because of dirt. The right one is OK.

Comment: sample images would be welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the image, you could split it up in different parts (say 4x4 subimages), compute variance in each sub image, and see if the difference between lowest and highest variance is big.

Comment: Tnax. Than's actually, what I did. I'v thought of a kind of sofisticated transformation making image black, if not homogenious. Or sth. like that :-)